# Can I call a Java static function from liquibase xml?

Tags: java, liquibase

I have an existing project which is on production. I am looking to update a column's value. And the business methods are ready. Can i call this function via liquibase xml? I would also need to pass an existing value from the table into the method.

```
<changeSet id="update_badges_hashes" author="Rakhunathan">
        <update tableName="badges">
            <column name="hashtags"  valueComputed="${net.compant.app.util.Generator.getData('1')}" />
        </update>
</changeSet>
```

This implementation throws error and I am looking for the correct way to do it.

Comment: Can you add error stack trace to question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something but as far as I know, if you need to execute some Java method then the only thing you can do is to create your custom changeSet.

You can use the `customChange`:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <customChange class="your.package.liquibase.YourJavaChangeSet"/>
</changeSet>
```

And Java class could look like this:

```
public class YourJavaChangeSet implements CustomTaskChange {

    @Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
        // your logic here
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfirmationMessage() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws SetupException {

    }

    @Override
    public void setFileOpener(ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor) {

    }

    @Override
    public ValidationErrors validate(Database database) {
        return null;
    }
}
```